# Unable to install Package control in sublime text 3

Tags: ubuntu, sublime-text-3

I had installed sublime text 3 using instructions for the [apt repository stable channel](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/linux_repositories.html). As the next logical step, I tried installing 'Package control' using 'Tools' > 'Install Package Control'. But even after waiting for 10-15 min there was no response. 
I have seen the following links.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38787206/sublime-text-manually-install-package-control

https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/package-control-not-working-at-all/29219/2

http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047606/uninstall-sublime-text-3-downloaded-and-installed-as-a-deb-from-ubuntu-18-04-lt

Answer (score 0):

I updated the repository using

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get upgrade

Also, I paused syncing with Dropbox. After this I tried again to install package control as in the question above. And voila within a 10 sec  a dialog box pops up informing that 'Package control has been successfully  installed'.